# How to extract a line from a text in a cell based on certain criteria

Tags: excel

I need to obtain a **date, timestamp** field captured from an excel cell containing lines of text based on a certain criteria

**A sample excel cell containing multiple lines of text data is shown below:**
**------------START OF THE SAMPLE TEXT FROM EXCEL CELL BELOW---------------------------------------------------------**-

2019-07-01 11:42:20 - Adeba Shariff (Work notes)

We check and found five (2 soap and 3 valid) messages and got failed at middleware (ISR.CXT.ESB.ERROR.DETAILS.LOCAL) due to the below error:

ERROR TEXT :

> [IBM][ODBC 20101 driver][Microsoft SQL Server]Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'Replenishment_PK'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Replenishment'. The duplicate key value is (MNPOKNI1N810210-E86-M, 598, Jul  1 2019 10:02AM).

Before Reprocessing :-

```
dis qs(ISR.CXT.ESB.ERROR.DETAILS.LOCAL) 
28 : dis qs(ISR.CXT.ESB.ERROR.DETAILS.LOCAL) 
AMQ8450I: Display queue status details. 
QUEUE(ISR.CXT.ESB.ERROR.DETAILS.LOCAL) 
TYPE(QUEUE) CURDEPTH(5) 
IPPROCS(0) LGETDATE(2019-06-30) 
LGETTIME(11.18.14) LPUTDATE(2019-07-01) 
LPUTTIME(10.02.58) MEDIALOG( ) 
MONQ(LOW) MSGAGE(25991) 
OPPROCS(0) QTIME(999999999, 999999999) 
UNCOM(NO)
```

Solution: We are ignoring these failure messages with a backup as it is a Violation of PRIMARY KEY issue. Please let us know if any action has to be taken from our end.

After Reprocessing :

```
dis qs(ISR.CXT.ESB.ERROR.DETAILS.LOCAL)
    29 : dis qs(ISR.CXT.ESB.ERROR.DETAILS.LOCAL)
AMQ8450I: Display queue status details.
   QUEUE(ISR.CXT.ESB.ERROR.DETAILS.LOCAL)
   TYPE(QUEUE)                             CURDEPTH(0)
   IPPROCS(0)                              LGETDATE(2019-07-01)
   LGETTIME(11.36.08)                      LPUTDATE(2019-07-01)
   LPUTTIME(10.02.58)                      MEDIALOG( )
   MONQ(LOW)                               MSGAGE(0)
   OPPROCS(0)                              QTIME(999999999, 999999999)
   UNCOM(NO)
```

Best Regards

2019-07-01 11:15:31 - Adeba Shariff (Work notes)
Before Reprocessing :-

```
dis qs(ISR.CXT.ESB.ERROR.DETAILS.LOCAL)
    28 : dis qs(ISR.CXT.ESB.ERROR.DETAILS.LOCAL)
AMQ8450I: Display queue status details.
   QUEUE(ISR.CXT.ESB.ERROR.DETAILS.LOCAL)
   TYPE(QUEUE)                             CURDEPTH(5)
   IPPROCS(0)                              LGETDATE(2019-06-30)
   LGETTIME(11.18.14)                      LPUTDATE(2019-07-01)
   LPUTTIME(10.02.58)                      MEDIALOG( )
   MONQ(LOW)                               MSGAGE(25991)
   OPPROCS(0)                              QTIME(999999999, 999999999)
   UNCOM(NO)
```

**2019-07-01 10:10:54** - Adeba Shariff (Work notes)
 Triage completed

2019-07-01 09:37:55 - Adeba Shariff (Work notes)
Acknowledged.

2019-07-01 07:57:44 - Shreya Inamdar (Work notes)
Tivoli Enterprise Portal Alert:

1. Date/Time Occurred: 07/01/19 07:50:25 3 Minutes 07/01/19 07:53:41
2. Severity:   CRITICAL or WARNING
3. Situation Name:  RL1_WMBLOG_ERROR
4. Impact: UNIX Logs
5. Situation Event Results:

brokerlog.log ERROR

> [IS.ISR.SalesReport] rlap1mqs:KUL /var/mqsi/common/log/ 07/01/19 07:52:29   2322Child SQL exceptionIIBP01HA1IS.ISR23003278SalesReportNode>SalesReport.ConvertToXML 0 0 07/01/19 07:52:29 /var/mqsi/common/log/ brokerlog.log [IS.ISR.SalesReport] 2322Child SQL exception
>   IIBP01HA1IS.ISR23003278SalesReportSalesReport.ConvertToXML

---------END OF THE SAMPLE CELL IN EXCEL WITH LINES OF TEXT------------------------------------------------------

I'm trying to extract the **date timestamp** from the above cell (highlighted in bold in the sample text above) with the text based on the condition "**Triage completed**".

Which in other words, I need a formula to extract 2019-07-01 10:10:54 (from the above cell data shown) which is the timestamp when the Triage has completed.

I have a bunch of cells with different texts in it, but all the cells have the text "Triage completed" within their cells and a timestamp right above this text which I want to extract.

I tried LEFT, MID, INDEX and FIND to no avail.

Appreciate if you could shed some light here. Thank you.

`=LEFT(A2, SEARCH("Triage completed",A2,1)-1)`
The result is not as expected

I expect the date timestamp to be extracted from the given cell above based on the condition that when it finds the string "Triage completed" in the cell.

Comment: Please note that

Comment: Please note that the following lines of text are in two different lines one next to the other (unlike how it is represented in the sample text shown in the question). That is "Triage Completed" text is in next line to the date timestamp shown in the text above (2019-07-01 10:10:54 - Adeba Shariff (Work notes))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest writing a User Defined Function (UDF) in VBA and utilizing Regular Expressions.

To enter this User Defined Function (UDF), `<alt-F11>` opens the Visual Basic Editor.
Ensure your project is highlighted in the Project Explorer window.
Then, from the top menu, select **Insert/Module** and
paste the code below into the window that opens.

To use this User Defined Function (UDF), enter a formula like `=triageComplete(A1)` in some cell.

If, in fact, the format is `<date/time … some text-newline-Triage Complete>`, and if the date/time is always in exactly the format you show, then try:

```
Option Explicit
Function triageComplete(S As String) As Date
    Dim RE As Object, MC As Object

Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .Global = True
    .ignorecase = True
    .Pattern = "\b(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s+\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\b.*\n.*Triage Completed"
    .MultiLine = True
    If .Test(S) = True Then
        Set MC = .Execute(S)
        triageComplete = MC(0).submatches(0)
    End If
End With
End Function
```

If the format might be different, you'll need to be more specific.

The above UDF works on your copy/pasted data, although you may have to format the cell where the formula returns its result.

Comment: Thank you for the quick turnaround. I tried the above code and it's returning #NAME? in the result cell. I tried formatting this cell but in vain. Am I missing something? and BTW - Data/Time is always in the same format as I've mentioned above.

Comment: I think I'm able to run it now and get the result. But the output I receive is only the time and not the date! I now see 10:10:54 but not the date!!

Comment: @user3736290 That is probably due to incorrect cell formatting.

Comment: I have obtained the desired result and I'm very thankful to you Ron! Thank you very much for making my life much easier with the code. Truly appreciate it! Have a good day Sir :)